# Make PowerShell suggests current folder content/items using the Tab key

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I'm new to PowerShell,

I'd like to navigate through the file system by getting the current folder content suggestions instead of cmdlets by clicking the `Tab` key just like in the CMD.

I don't want to use the `dir` cmdlet, I want to walk through the different items by clicking on the `Tab` key.

Is that possible and how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type ex. `a<tab>`, you will always get file/folders starting with `a` before it shows any cmdlets and commands in `PATH`-locations.

If you only want files and folders, type `.\<tab>`

Comment: Ah I see, all I need is I should start typing fist, I couldn't notice that before, thx !